# Two ResourceManagers Use one as fallback of another

Tags: c#, resx

Given I have two resourceManagers:

```
var mgr1 = new ResourceManager("NS1.StringResources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var mgr2 = new ResourceManager("NS2.OtherStringResources", _otherAssembly);
```

Is there a way that i can merge them? Or Their resourcesets. such that i can have one manager or resourceset.

Comment: `ResourceManager` isn't sealed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with something similar as it seems dictionary is only way to go.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetTotalResourceSet(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> set;
        if (_resources.TryGetValue(culture.Name, out set))
            return set;

        var wl = getWhitelabelResourceSet(culture);
        var loc = getLocalResourceSet(culture);

        var dict = loc.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
           .ToDictionary(x => { return x.Key.ToString(); }, x =>
           {
               if (x.Value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                   return x.Value.ToString();
               return "";
           });

        if (wl != null)
        {
            var wlDict = wl.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
               .ToDictionary(x => { return x.Key.ToString(); }, x =>
               {
                   if (x.Value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                       return x.Value.ToString();
                   return "";
               });
            set = wlDict.Concat(dict.Where(kvp => !wlDict.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            set = dict;
        }


        if (set != null)
        {
            _resources.TryAdd(culture.Name, set);
        }
        return set;
    }
```

Comment: To note is it allows for a "override" assembly to be null

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty but you will end up in a Merged dictionary:

```
var mgr1 = new ResourceManager("NS1.StringResources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
      var mgr2 = new ResourceManager("NS2.OtherStringResources", _otherAssembly);
      var combined = new Dictionary<string, object>();
      ResourceSet resourceSet = mgr1.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
      foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet) {
        string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
        object resource = entry.Value;
        combined.Add(resourceKey, resource);
      }
      resourceSet = mgr2.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
      foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet) {
        string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
        object resource = entry.Value;
        combined.Add(resourceKey, resource);
      }
```